# How can force it only on an hourly using android TimePicker

Tags: android, android-timepicker

I would like to use `TimePicker` to create a form in which the user only receives input in time units as follows:

```
03:00
15:00
17:00
```

Is there a way?

**** This is my TimePicker ****

```
  protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

    // Get the calander
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    // From calander get the year, month, day, hour, minute
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    switch (id) {
        case Date_id:

            // Open the datepicker dialog
            return new DatePickerDialog(GoodbyePetTimeDateSelectActivity.this, date_listener, year,
                    month, day);
        case Time_id:

            // Open the timepicker dialog
            return new TimePickerDialog(GoodbyePetTimeDateSelectActivity.this, time_listener, hour,
                    minute, false);

    }
    return null;
}

// Date picker dialog
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date_listener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // store the data in one string and set it to text
        String date1 = String.valueOf(month) + "/" + String.valueOf(day)
                + "/" + String.valueOf(year);
        set_date.setText(date1);
    }
};

TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener time_listener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hour, int minute) {
        // store the data in one string and set it to text
        String time1 = String.valueOf(hour) + ":" + String.valueOf(minute);
        set_time.setText(time1);
    }
};
```

I want to delete input min 
only receiver per hour

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by just changing the following line:

```
String time1 = String.valueOf(hour) + ":" + String.valueOf(minute);
```

to

```
String time1 = String.valueOf(hour) + ":00";
```

Answer (score 0):

From the question,

> TimePicker to create a form in which the user only receives input in time units

I believe you want the TimePicker to enable user only to select the hour and put 00 in the minute, not programmatically remove or exclude the minute value. For implementing that just use the following class I'm providing below and use it from wherever you prefer:

`CustomTimePickerDialog`

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class CustomTimePickerDialog extends TimePickerDialog {

    private final static int TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL = 60;
    private TimePicker mTimePicker;
    private final OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener;

    public CustomTimePickerDialog(Context context, OnTimeSetListener listener,
                                  int hourOfDay, int minute, boolean is24HourView) {
        super(context, TimePickerDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT, null, hourOfDay,
                minute / TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL, is24HourView);
        mTimeSetListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateTime(int hourOfDay, int minuteOfHour) {
        mTimePicker.setCurrentHour(hourOfDay);
        mTimePicker.setCurrentMinute(minuteOfHour / TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        switch (which) {
            case BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                if (mTimeSetListener != null) {
                    mTimeSetListener.onTimeSet(mTimePicker, mTimePicker.getCurrentHour(),
                            mTimePicker.getCurrentMinute() * TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL);
                }
                break;
            case BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                cancel();
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        try {
            Class<?> classForid = Class.forName("com.android.internal.R$id");
            Field timePickerField = classForid.getField("timePicker");
            mTimePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(timePickerField.getInt(null));
            Field field = classForid.getField("minute");

            NumberPicker minuteSpinner = (NumberPicker) mTimePicker
                    .findViewById(field.getInt(null));
            minuteSpinner.setMinValue(0);
            minuteSpinner.setMaxValue((60 / TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL) - 1);
            List<String> displayedValues = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 60; i += TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL) {
                displayedValues.add(String.format("%02d", i));
            }
            minuteSpinner.setDisplayedValues(displayedValues
                    .toArray(new String[displayedValues.size()]));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Call this from your activity like this:

```
    Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    CustomTimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
    mTimePicker = new CustomTimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
            tv.setText( selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
        }
    }, hour, minute, false);
    mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
    mTimePicker.show();
```

This will provide the user with a simple time picker dialog but restricting the minute values to 00 like this, see this screenshot of the app:

[image: CustomTimePickerDialog]

Follow this [gist](https://gist.github.com/SaadAAkash/fff10eda851736e30d76d7533186f927) I've created to view the whole project code:

https://gist.github.com/SaadAAkash/fff10eda851736e30d76d7533186f927

Comment: You can also use this code to set your preferred minute intervals as you wish in any of the other projects too. Hope this helps @ttimfirst